# Reverse foreign key relation in django serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Can I save data in django in a reverse foreign key relation.

Suppose I have models,

```
 class Author(models.Model):
     author_id = models.SlugField(default=None, blank=True)
     author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

 class Article(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     article_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Suppose I want to save all articles with their author data what type of serializer should I use.
I am receiving data in this form:

```
  article_data =[
       {
          "article_title":"one title",
          "content":"content",
          "author":{
             "author_id":"2",
             "author_name":"some name",
          }
       },
       {
          "article_title":"one title",
          "content":"content",
          "author":{
             "author_id":"2",
             "author_name":"some name",
          }
       }
  ]
```

How should I write my serializer to save such data. I dont want to write my logic views file.
I dont want to loop over all my articles and then save article and author separately using two serialzer.
What I want is calling a single serializer and passing the entire list to it:

```
 saveArticleAndAuthor(article_data, many=True)
```

the serialzier must save author data to author table and rest of the data to article table.

Answer (score 1):

you need two classes in `serializer.py`

```
class Author_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
          model = Author
          fields = ["author_id", "author_name"]
```

and and second must be under Author_serializer

```
class saveArticleAndAuthor_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
          model = Article
          fields = ["author", "article_title", "content"]
     author = Author_serializer()
```

in `views.py` you use only `saveArticleAndAuthor_serializer` and it will serialize `Author_serializer` as "second level depth"